# How this code works? Selection Sort Python

Tags: python, sorting

hi I don't understand how this code work. Explain me pls. Thank you.

```
#how this function finds the smallest element of the array.
def findSmallest(arr):
  smallest = arr[0] 
  smallest_index = 0
  for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i] < smallest: #--> why this is here and what does it mean?
      smallest_index = i
      smallest = arr[i]      
  return smallest_index

def selectionSort(arr):
  newArr = []
  for i in range(len(arr)):
      smallest = findSmallest(arr)
      newArr.append(arr.pop(smallest))
  return newArr

print(selectionSort([5, 3, 6, 2, 10]))
```

how "findSmallest" function finds the smallest element of the array?

Comment: _why this is here and what does it mean?_ That line of code compares the current element to the smallest element seen so far.

Comment: In (if arr[i] < smallest:)  smallest is a variable which stores the values of smallest of an array, and this condition is checking, if any element is an array is small then "smallest" variable.

Answer (score 3):

The line you questioned specifically is comparing values. If the value at the current index (calculated by the for-loop) is less than the value stored in smallest (originally the first value in the list), then store this value as the new smallest value. I added more comments to the code to explain the rest of it.

```
#how this function finds the smallest element of the array.
def findSmallest(arr): #function with a parameter to hold an array
  smallest = arr[0]  #index 0 of passed array
  smallest_index = 0 
  for i in range(1, len(arr)): 
    if arr[i] < smallest: #if the value in the array at the index of i is smaller than the value at the index of 0
      smallest_index = i #the index of the smallest number is now at the position of i
      smallest = arr[i] #the smallest number is now the number at the index of i     
  return smallest_index #return the index position of the smallest number

def selectionSort(arr): #function passed an array
  newArr = [] 
  for i in range(len(arr)): #loop through passed array
      smallest = findSmallest(arr) #call the findSmallest function
      newArr.append(arr.pop(smallest)) #remove the smallest number from the passed array and add it to the new one. Repeat until passed array is empty
  return newArr #return the new array

print(selectionSort([5, 3, 6, 2, 10]))
```

Answer (score 1):

By reading it, looks like it orders given elements and puts them into an array from smallest to largest based on value. To answer your question about `line 5`, it compares the stored integer value `i` to the other ones in `selectionSort` so that the following code can print the sorted array. `def selectionSort(arr)` has a variable `smallest` that uses `findSmallest` to append the list of elements in numerical order.